# String[] to byte[] 2 characters into a byte?

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have an string which contains the contents of an SREC file. In an SREC file, every 2 characters is a byte (which is an instruction in this case).

if i make the string into a string array, and then convert an element of that string array into a byte (at least i think that's what i'm doing), it still separates the characters making each character into a byte... how do i get around this?

Example 1:

```
String[] myFile = new String[]{"s1", "my", "na", "me","is"}; 
try 
{
    byte[] byteArray = myFile[1].getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(byteArray)); 
}
```

Result: 
[109, 0, 121, 0]

Comment: How can every two characters be a byte? Do you mean that every character is two bytes?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "every 2 characters is a byte"? On a side note, your output is a UTF-16 representation of the string "my" (`myFile[1]`), and `char` in Java is _"a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive)."_ ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

Comment: `UTF-16LE` will turn each character into two bytes.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov yes, i got that thanks, as others have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying UTF-16LE as an encoding. That will always use 2 bytes for every Java `char`. If you don't want to use 2 bytes per character, don't use UTF-16...

If two characters are represented by a single byte in an SREC file, then you need to have some kind of mapping from `String` to `Byte` - there are 2<sup>32</sup> possible 2-character strings, but only 256 possible bytes. Assuming this is a fixed mapping, you may just want to hard-code a `Map<String, Byte>`, and fetch the value from the map.

(If the values were really just hex, you could use existing hex parsing code - but none of the sample strings you've given is a valid pair of hex digits.)

Comment: @BlueMonster: We have no idea how strings are meant to map to bytes in SREC files. You haven't even told us what SREC is. Do you have a specification you could link to?

Comment: the SREC is not really important, the important part is that i'm reading something in from a file into a string... and from that string, each 2 characters is an instruction, and i need each 2 characters to be a byte...

Comment: @BlueMonster: "the SREC is not really important" - of course it is! If you want to be able to map two characters to a single byte, then that's a protocol-specific transformation. I get the fact that each two characters form an instruction, which is then represented by a byte... but that mapping is SREC-specific.

Comment: @BlueMonster: It looks like after the S0, S1 etc header, it's just hex - so the sample data in your question is unhelpful, and you can just use one of the many hex parsing libraries, such as Apache Commons Codec.

Comment: @BlueMonster: What do you mean? The document you gave us showed us that the contents of each record is hex. So parse the hex representation of each record into a byte array, e.g. with Apache Commons Codec. I don't see the problem.

Comment: sigh*.... i think it's because you don't know what my program is supposed to do... either that, or i have a misunderstanding in my logic.... anywho, i'll look into Apache Common's Codec... although i don't see why i would need that to make a byte array from a string....?

Comment: @BlueMonster: Well you can write your own hex parser if you want, but why would you want to reinvent the wheel? And no, we haven't got any idea what your program is meant to do - but your sample data is clearly invalid in terms of the document you referenced, given that "my", "na" etc aren't valid pairs of hex digits.

Answer (score 1):

SREC converts bytes into hexidecimal encoded numbers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_%28file_format%29

This is the opposite of what you appear to be trying to do.

> Ok, what should i use?

Write a loop where each byte of a String is converted into it equivalent hexidecimal.  There are endless examples available.

Comment: i need to manipulate some things in my program and send it back to another method which will no longer be using the srec file... i just need each two characters i read in to be converted into a byte...

Comment: Can you add an example of what mapping you want to do to the question as there is no standard way of doing this? (rather than referring to  SREC which does something completely different)

Comment: I suspect your actual requirement is to follow the SREC specification and turn each character to two bytes (in hex).